# Kubernetes default QoS for whole namespace

Tags: kubernetes, qos

Is there any method of setting **default** QoS for all of the nodes from given namespace? Or just set QoS on namespace level instead of pod level.
I mean the situation where every existing and every newly created pod will have this default setting for given namespace.

Eg. All pods in namespace `kube-system` or `super-important` got QoS level "guaranted".

I want to set the QoS in such a way that in case of any problems with the resources pods from `kube-system` (or other important groups/namespaces), they be removed last, later than the less important ones.

P.S. I got advice about admission-controllers but i didn't see correlation to QoS.

Comment: Does priority and (in particular) pre-emption map to what you have in mind https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/pod-priority-preemption/ ?

Comment: Also of interest may be https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/60596 , https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/guaranteed-scheduling-critical-addon-pods/ and https://github.com/coreos/flannel/issues/925

Comment: I guess your thinking is more along the lines of https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/issues/4415 It is worth looking at https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/pod-priority-preemption/#interactions-of-pod-priority-and-qos as I'm not sure whether or not you're thinking of a scenario where the pods are exceeding their requests

Answer (score 1):

It's possible. Some basic information about QoS:

> Kubernetes uses QoS classes to make decisions about scheduling and
> evicting Pods.
>
> #### For a Pod to be given a QoS class of Guaranteed:
>
> - Every Container in the Pod must have a memory limit and a memory
>   request, and they must be the same.
> - Every Container in the Pod must
>   have a CPU limit and a CPU request, and they must be the same.
>
> #### A Pod is given a QoS class of Burstable if:
>
> - The Pod does not meet the criteria for QoS class Guaranteed. At least
>   one Container in the Pod has a memory or CPU request.
>
> #### For a Pod to be given a QoS class of BestEffort:
>
> - The Containers in the Pod must not have any memory or CPU limits or
>   requests.

Here is an example of how to set the Guaranteed QoS for all pods in the namespace qos-test.

Let's create a namespace qos-test:

```
$ kubectl create namespace qos-test
```

Next, let's create a LimitRange object YAML file (CPU and Memory should be present, limits and requests should be the same):

```
$ cat <<EOF > limitRange.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: LimitRange
metadata:
  name: mem-limit-gua
spec:
  limits:
  - default:
      cpu: 100m
      memory: 512Mi
    defaultRequest:
      cpu: 100m
      memory: 256Mi
    type: Container
EOF
```

Then let’s apply it to the namespace qos-test:

```
$ kubectl create -f limitRange.yaml --namespace=qos-test
```

Now, let's create a pod (CPU or Memory requests and limits must not be present in Pod spec):

```
$ cat <<EOF > default-pod.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: default-pod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: default-ctr
    image: nginx
EOF

$ kubectl create -f default-pod.yaml --namespace=qos-test
```

Finally, let's check what we've got:

```
$ kubectl get namespaces
...
$ kubectl get limitrange --all-namespaces -o wide
...
$ kubectl get limitrange -o yaml -n qos-test
...
$ kubectl get pod default-pod -o yaml -n qos-test

apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  ...
  name: default-pod
  namespace: qos-test
  ...
spec:
  containers:
  - image: nginx
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    name: default-ctr
    resources:
      limits:
        cpu: 100m
        memory: 256Mi
      requests:
        cpu: 100m
        memory: 256Mi
    ...
status:
  ...
  hostIP: 10.0.2.15
  phase: Running
  podIP: 172.17.0.10
  qosClass: Guaranteed
  ...
```

As you can see `default-pod` got the `qosClass: Guaranteed`.

To create pods with different QoS please refer to this part of documentation:

- [Configure Quality of Service for Pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/quality-service-pod/)

You can find more details about configuring default limits for a Namespace in this article:

- [Configure Default Memory Requests and Limits for a Namespace](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/manage-resources/memory-default-namespace/)

Comment: Thanks for the advice, that's probably what I meant.
From what I understand, the pod automatically gets QoS status "guaranteed" if only the limits and requirements are set at the same level? I had read this documentation before and it was not obvious to me.

Comment: You're right. Limits and requests for CPU and memory should be present in spec of running pod and limits values should equal request values. CPUlim==CPUreq, MEMlim==MEMreq.