# How do I set OpenShift QoS setting on a container's yaml template file?

Tags: openshift-origin

Using OpenShift Origin (v3.9.0).  How do I set the quality of service (QoS) tier of a pod.  Specifically, what yaml key path do I use to specify this value in a DeploymentConfig yaml template?

There is endless docs describing and viewing QoS settings but literally nothing to actually specify it in a config file:

https://github.com/openshift/openshift-docs/blob/master/dev_guide/compute_resources.adoc#quality-of-service-tiers

```
# Example yaml template..so where do I specify QoS settings in here?
- kind: DeploymentConfig
  apiVersion: v1
  metadata:
    name: ${NAME}
  spec:
    strategy:
      type: Rolling
    triggers:
      - type: ConfigChange
    replicas: 3
    selector:
      name: ${NAME}
    template:
      metadata:
        labels:
          name: ${NAME}
      spec:
        securityContext:
          runAsUser: 1000
        containers:
        - env:
          image: ${IMAGE}
...
```

Most importantly where can I get a full description of the DeploymentConfig schema?  I want to see every single possible key available and all default values when optional settings are left out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quotas and Limitranges are what you're looking for. The "QoS-Settings" are nothing you put into the DeploymentConfig-Part of a template - it is part of the configuration of the project you're running your deployments in.
I'd refer to [the OpenShift Documentation](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.9/dev_guide/compute_resources.html) for this. [This is also really helpful](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.9/admin_guide/overcommit.html#qos-classes)

Regarding all available keys for the DeploymentConfig object, I'd also refer to the [OpenShift Documentation regarding the Object Schema](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.9/rest_api/apis-apps.openshift.io/v1.DeploymentConfig.html#object-schema).

Comment: [Overcommitting](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.9/admin_guide/overcommit.html#qos-classes) states that each pod can be assigned one of three different QoS classes which is what I want to do.  And this assignment is determined by the project the pod is in?  So I need to edit my project in a way where any pods spawned in that namespace will automatically have the QoS class attached?

If I'm understanding it correctly [Quotas](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.9/dev_guide/compute_resources.html) is for limiting the number of pods spawned with a particular QoS.

Comment: I think I understand it now.  The section on [limits](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.9/dev_guide/compute_resources.html#quality-of-service-tiers) says that I have to specify the limits of a container and then the QoS is a derived value based on the limits and the project's quotas.  I was thrown off because I usually associate limits with the minimum required cpu/mem to run an application, not it's priority for eviction.  Anyways, I will experiment with this but may need a different approach to make our critical pods have fewer evictions.

Answer (score 2):

This [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51986300/kubernetes-default-qos-for-whole-namespace) is the same question but for kubernetes.  Missed it on my initial googling.
The Kubernetes [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/quality-service-pod/) provides an exact step by step guide.